# Interview Complexity Question: If statement and comparison complexity

Tags: if-statement, comparison, complexity-theory

I was studying some interview questions and came across this problem right here. [Question Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPzwd.png)

I understood everything for the most part except the part that I have boxed in red. If every string within the array has been sorted. Then shouldn't sorting the array take only O(a log a)? Why did they multiply that by O(s)? It explains that the string comparison when sorting would take O(s), with s being the largest string size. That makes sense... However, I assumed the comparison would look something like this...

```
if ( array[x].equals(array[y]) ) {...}
```

Don't if statements take a complexity of O(1)? So shouldn't that be disregarded? I might be wrong but i think i had read that executing if statements and any other imbedded statement (Not Loop) would take a complexity of O(1). Please correct me if I am wrong and enlighten me on how to calculate complexity properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's  sorting, so the comparison would be 'a' > 'b'.
Now, imaging you have two strings like these:

```
'aaaaaaaa'
'aaaaaaab'
```

It would take S steps to get to the very last character to determine which string is larger. This operation is performed for each string comparison, hence we multiply it by S.

Comment: So if statements are not O(1)? How do you determine when an if statement is O(1) and when it is not?

Comment: It's not about 'if' statement, it's about data structure you use. For example, comparing two integers is not the same as comparing two arrays of integers, because you would have to go over each element of both arrays, which is O(n). Think of string as an array, so going over a string would take O(n) as well.